# switch to another activity with swipe is not working

Tags: java, android

My requirement :-
I have two activities..When I swipe it will go to another activity..

So,I have :--
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_getservice);

  gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

 class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
  //handle 'swipe left' action only

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {


         if(event2.getX() < event1.getX()){


          //switch another activity
             Intent intent = new Intent(
               MainActivity.this, Join_form.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();
         }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and **Join_form.java**

```
public class Join_form extends  Activity {

     private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

     class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
      //handle 'swipe left' action only

         @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                  if(event2.getX() > event1.getX()){


                   //switch another activity
                      Intent intent = new Intent(
                              Join_form.this, MainActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      finish();
                  }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_getservice.xml** is:--

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       >

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0b2607"
     >
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Form" 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<View android:id="@+id/division1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#999999" />


   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView android:text="Name :"
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />

      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:hint="name"
    android:layout_weight="1" />    

</LinearLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/division2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#999999" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView android:text="Address :"
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />

      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:hint="address"
    android:layout_weight="1" />    






</LinearLayout>

<View
            android:id="@+id/division9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:background="#999999" />
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

  <TextView
    android:text="You Are :"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
   android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <Spinner

    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />    

</LinearLayout>
<View
            android:id="@+id/division3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:background="#999999" />
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

  <TextView
    android:text="hii"
    android:id="@+id/txt4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
   android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <Spinner

    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />    

</LinearLayout>
<View
            android:id="@+id/division10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:background="#999999" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/check"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

     <TextView
    android:text="Select your reqirements:-"
    android:id="@+id/the"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/lay1">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="apple"
            android:tag="apple"
              android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana" 
            android:tag="banana" 
              android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="water_milon" 
            android:tag="water_milon"
              android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/lay2">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="guava" 
            android:tag="guava" 
              android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="panir" 
             android:tag="panir"
               android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chatni" 
             android:tag="chatni"
               android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
<View
            android:id="@+id/division6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:background="#999999"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Write your message(optional) :"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
   android:background="@drawable/edit_text_stle"
   android:hint="write something ">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<View
            android:id="@+id/division7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:background="#999999"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="send"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

**activity_main.xml** is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

But I can not swipe the page. It is not going to the another page. Why it is happening?
Where is the problem?

Comment: check this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/12/detect-gestures-of-swipe-to-switch.html

Comment: @ Jignesh Jain,  I am following this one..But i dont know why my swipe is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @k3v1n4ud3. Let me just expand a bit since I can't really comment due to lack of karma.

With ViewPager (inside MainActivity.java) + MainFragment (Fragment)+ JoinForm (Fragment), you would be able to get away without having a listener for fling. It would just handle the swiping part automatically for you.

Just think about it like this: You have a brain (MainActivity w/ViewPager) and two arms (the first and second fragment you're implementing).

1. Create a MainActivity that would contain your ViewPager.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);

   //somehow fill the adapter
                       MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()); //=== required as per the MyAdapter class

                       //set the adapter
                       myViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                       // display first fragment
                       myViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
   ```

   }
2. Create an Adapter that extends FragmentPagerAdapter (or FragmentStatePagerAdapter). It looks like this:

   ```
   class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private final int[] titles = {R.string.main_activity_title, R.string.join_activity_title};
   private final String[] fragments = {
       MainFragment.class.getName(),
       JoinFragment.class.getName()
       };
   private final Context ctx;

   public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context ctx) {
       super(fm);
       this.ctx = ctx;
       }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return ctx.getString(titles[position]);
       }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return Fragment.instantiate(ctx, fragments[position]);
       }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return titles.length;
       }
   }
   ```
3. (Optional) See those title thingys on top of each page, the ones you could click so you could fast forward to the other page? They're called tabhosts.

To use them, simply add a tabhost to your MainActivity layout and add this logic in MainActivity.java:

```
    myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            myTabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    //set titles
    for (int i = 0; i < myAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        myTabHost.addTab(
                myTabHost.newTab()
                        .setText(myAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this)
        );
    }
```

4. (Optional) Animations on 'fling'
So to animate when you switch fragments, you simple have to call this:

```
    myViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DefaultTransformer());
```

And you can also customize it to your will.

I apologize if there are typos and other stuff. But this should cover majority of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should change the architecture, transform your 2 activities into fragment and place them inside a viewPager. The viewPager will handle the sliding part for you.

Comment: I already have tried this . http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-circle-style-example/   .But there were Some problem thats why i need to do this..

Comment: If  I extends fragment then some methods are not supporting..BTW can u give me any example?

Comment: which methods aren't supported?